# Linked Server Error for PDW

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, permission-denied, parallel-data-warehouse

I am trying to connect to a PDW instance from an SMP server. The linked server is established and I can view the PDW databases from SMP. But when I try to select data from PDW, here's the error that I get:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "x.x.x.x,x" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 104386, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Stored procedure sp_tables_info_90_rowset_64 does not exist or is not supported.
```

Could this be related to permissions on my ID. I am connected to SMP server using windows authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDW [documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45294) states:

> SQL statements must be submitted using the linked server EXECUTE
>   statement. Using the EXECUTE statement avoids using four-part names
>   for objects, which is not supported by SQL Server PDW. For example:
>
> Use this: EXEC ('SELECT * FROM AdventureWorksPDW2012.dbo.dimCustomer')
>   AT PDWLINK;
>
> Don’t use this: SELECT * FROM
>   PDWLINK.AdventureWorksPDW2012.dbo.dimCustomer

So I wouldn't expect to be able to browse the linked server and get a list of databases. You can run queries though.

For the reference of others, the PDW/APS documentation explains how to create a SQL Server linked server that connects to the PDW:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'SQLNCLI', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
@server = N'PDWLINK', @srvproduct=N'PDW', 
@provider=N'SQLNCLI', @provstr=N'Server=<ip_control_node_cluster>,17001', @catalog=N'<database>';
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
@rmtsrvname=N'PDWLINK',@useself=N'False',
@rmtuser=N'<PDW_login_name>',@rmtpassword='<PDW_login_password>'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'rpc',
@optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'rpc out',
@optvalue=N'true'
GO

-- The options below are not required
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'collation compatible',
@optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'data access',
@optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'dist',
@optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'pub',
@optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'sub',
@optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'connect timeout',
@optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'collation name',
@optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'lazy schema validation',
@optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'query timeout',
@optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'use remote collation',
@optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption
@server=N'PDWLINK', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion',
@optvalue=N'false'
GO
```

Comment: That was brilliant! Ir worked for me. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Can you let me know what would be the "CTAS" syntax if I am trying to load data from PDW into an SMP server?

Comment: Create a table. Then INSERT mytable EXEC ('select whatever') AT

Comment: @TriumphSpitfire if I have answered your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: Accepted it. Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: How to create a linked server for sql server PDW

Comment: @N.Dinesh.Reddy I have edited the answer to include the SQL for creating the linked servers.